# Python Matplotlib plot with x-axis labels correctly aligned and matching colors for series and errors

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am looking to plot some data from Pandas Dataframes using Matplotlib. I need to have control over the various properties of the plot. I am having difficulty with 2 properties:

a. Correct spacing for custom x-axis lables
b. How to plot a data series and its error bars with the same color

I have the following Dataframes in Python Pandas:

```
x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('ABCDE'))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('ABCDE'))
x_err = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('ABCDE'))
y_err = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,5), columns = list('ABCDE'))
x.insert(0,'Name',['Temp_C','Pressure_Rear','Barometric_High','Facility_depletion_rate']
y.insert(0,'Name',['Temp_C','Pressure_Rear','Barometric_High','Facility_depletion_rate']
x_err.insert(0,'Name',['Temp_C','Pressure_Rear','Barometric_High','Facility_depletion_rate']
y_err.insert(0,'Name',['Temp_C','Pressure_Rear','Barometric_High','Facility_depletion_rate']
```

In the dataframe `x`, each column gives the x co-ordinates. In the dataframe `y`, each column gives the corresponding y co-ordinates.

I am looking to plot y vs x in a scatter plot, where the points are connected y lines like this plot: http://40.media.tumblr.com/2bf0909609003f549e0d03406dc5a2dd/tumblr_mik00mS7rv1s6xcwuo1_1280.png
I also need to put error bars (`x_err` is the x-error and `y_err` is the y_error)

In each of these dataframes, there are 5 columns. The column headers must be in the legend and the x-axis needs to have labels.
The x-axis labels should be **'Temp_C'**,**'Pressure_Rear'**,**'Barometric_High'** and **'Facility_depletion_rate'**.

Here is the code that I have and a sample output is shown at the end of this post:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.set_facecolor('white')

for i in range(1,len(x.columns.tolist())):
    ax.errorbar(x.iloc[:,i], y.iloc[:,i], yerr=y_err.iloc[:,i], xerr=x_err.iloc[:,i], fmt='o') #generate plot for each set of errors (x and y) in the x-variable column list
    plt.plot(x.iloc[:,i], y.iloc[:,i], linestyle='-', marker='o', linewidth=1.5, label = x.columns.tolist()[i])

ttl = 'Room conditions - tracking monitor'
xtitle = 'Type of reading'
ytitle = 'Reading value (units)'
title_font = {'fontname':'Times New Roman', 'size':'28', 'color':'black', 'weight':'bold','verticalalignment':'bottom'} #Bottom vertical alignment for more space
axis_font = {'fontname':'Constantia', 'size':'26'}
axis_tick_font = {'fontname':'Times New Roman', 'size':'20'}

#plt.legend(loc='upper left')
ax.set_xticklabels(x.Name.tolist())
ax.tick_params(axis='x', pad=10)

plt.title(ttl, **title_font)
plt.xlabel(xtitle,**axis_font)
plt.ylabel(ytitle,**axis_font)
plt.xticks(**axis_tick_font)
plt.yticks(**axis_tick_font)

params = {'legend.fontsize': 20} #set legend properties
pl.rcParams.update(params)
plt.legend(loc = 1, prop={'family':title_font['fontname']}, numpoints = 1)

plt.show()
```

Here are the two problems I am having and questions about these:

1. The x-axis labels are completely mis-aligned. Is there a way to
   print the labels such that:

   a. they are aligned with the data points. By this I mean that the x-axis labels should be aligned with the x co-ordinates which are given in each column of the dataframe `x`.i.e. `x.iloc[:,1], y.iloc[:,1]` are the x and y co-ordinates for the dataset **A**, `x.iloc[:,2], y.iloc[:,2]` are the x and y co-ordinates for the dataset **B**. I need the x-axis labels to **ONLY** be aligned with `x.iloc[:,1], y.iloc[:,1]`.

   b. the labels are equally spaced from eachother and from the left and right border
2. The color of the error bars is not the same as the color of the data series. For example, if data series **'A'** is blue, is there a way [image]to force errorbars for **'A'** to also be blue?

Comment: Could you clarify to which data points the labels should be aligned too (regarding question 1a)

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning that. I have updated the OP now. Regarding the answer to your question: I would need the x-axis labels to be aligned with the 2nd column of the dataframe named `x`. See 1a. from the OP for a more detailed description.